# " echo" in bash script empty file

Tags: bash, echo

I have problem with echo command I need export data to csv but its empty file

```
#!/bin/bash 
while read domain
do
    ownname= whois $domain | grep -A 1 -i "Administrative Contact:" |cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed 's/ //' | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/ \n/,/;ta'
    echo -e  "$ownname" >> test.csv 
done < dom.txt
```

Comment: You're running the `whois` command with the extra environment variable `ownname` set to an empty string.  You need `ownname=$(...)` notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use command substitution to store command's output in a shell variable:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while read domain; do
    ownname=$(whois $domain | grep -A 1 -i "Administrative Contact:" |cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed 's/ //' | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/ \n/,/;ta')
    echo -e  "$ownname" >> test.csv
done
```

**PS:** I haven't tested all the piped commands.

Comment: It is [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), not [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).